# How do I fix the "The each() function is deprecated" error?

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7.6.0 on a server with PHP version 7.2.11.

I get this error message.

> Deprecated function: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in menu_set_active_trail() (line 2405 of C:\xampp\htdocs\portailcommerce\includes\menu.inc).

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can fix it by providing a patch to Drupal core and take part in the discussion to get it merged. Before it gets merged you could use your patch to get rid of the warning until then.

Comment: There is no need to provide a patch. Drupal 7 removed every usage of `each()` from PHP code since Drupal 7.61.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just update Drupal 7 to latest version which, as I am writing this answer, is version 7.64. Drupal 7 doesn't use `each()` in PHP since November 7, 2018, as the [CHANGELOG.txt](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/CHANGELOG.txt?h=7.x) file says. (See the last line of the part I quoted.)

> Drupal 7.61, 2018-11-07
>
> - File upload validation functions and `hook_file_validate()` implementations are
>     now always passed the correct file URI.
> - The default form cache expiration of 6 hours is now configurable (API
>     addition: https://www.drupal.org/node/2857751).
> - Allowed callers of `drupal_http_request()` to optionally specify an explicit
>     Host header.
> - Allowed the + character to appear in usernames.
> - PHP 7.2: Fixed Archive_Tar incompatibility.
> - PHP 7.2: Removed deprecated function `each()`.

As long as you use at least Drupal 7.61, you will fix the error you shown, which (in your case) is caused from [`menu_set_active_trail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_trail/7.x). (The code shown in the documentation page doesn't show any line using `each()` because the code has been updated to the latest Drupal 7 version.)

If you are using third-party modules, you could still see that error, but caused by other functions/methods. In that case, you need to update all the modules you are using on that site.
If this doesn't fix other *The each() function is deprecated* errors, you need to check the issue queue for every third-party module you are using, and verify there are patches for fixing that error.